# Unable to post data

Tags: laravel

> Hello, it is a very important project for me. I wrote an api and I want to pull data from 2 different sites with this api. While you can pull healthy data from one site, empty results are returned due to captcha from the other site. Now I scraped data from the same site before using pyhton selenium, bs4, but I can't scrape it with laravel api. I'm testing this info from postman.

- The solution of the captcha is to combine my pyhton file, which I have provided, with my laravel api file, if possible, by converting the captcha to audio and then to text, which skips this part.
- Another method is to write a pyhton service that can work with the captcha(pyhton) file.
- The last and actually the most useful method for me if I can provide action is to skip captcha with my laravel service without entering the captcha event. I tried skipping by changing the cookie, but it was a very tiring and unhealthy method. I want to trick some kind of captcha here.

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Services\Mde;
    use App\Core\ServiceResponse;
    use App\Interfaces\IPricePredictionService;

    class PricePredictionService extends BaseMDeService implements IPricePredictionService
    {
        /**
         * @param mixed $brand
         * @param mixed $model
         * @param mixed $kilometerFrom
         * @param mixed $kilometerTo
         * @param mixed $yearFrom
         * @param mixed $yearTo
         * @param mixed $fuelTypes
         * @param mixed $gearBoxes
         * @param mixed $powerFrom
         * @param mixed $powerTo
         *
         * @return ServiceResponse
         */
        public function getByParameters(
            $brand,
            $model,
            $kilometerFrom,
            $kilometerTo,
            $yearFrom,
            $yearTo,
            $fuelTypes,
            $gearBoxes,
            $powerFrom,
            $powerTo
        ): ServiceResponse
        {
        $endpoint = $this->baseUrl . '&ms=' . $brand . '%3B' . $model;
        $priceList = [];
        for ($pageCounter = 1; $pageCounter <= 50; $pageCounter++) {
            $parameters = [
                'ml' => $kilometerFrom,
                'ml%3A' => $kilometerTo, // duzelt
                'fr' => $yearFrom, // duzelt
                'fr%3A' => $yearTo, // duzelt
                'fuel' => implode(' ', $fuelTypes), //ft=DIESEL
                'gear' => implode(' ', $gearBoxes), //tr=MANUAL_GEAR
                'powertype' => 'kw',
                'pw' => $powerFrom, // duzelt
                'pw%3A' => $powerTo, // duzelt
                'page' => $pageCounter,
            ];

            $response = $this->client->get($endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($parameters), [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                    //'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Accept-Language'  => 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' //,
                ],
            ]);
            $clean1 = str_replace(["\n", "\t", "\r", "  "], null, $response->getBody()->getContents());
            $clean2 = str_replace(["&quot;"], null, $clean1);
            $clean3 = preg_replace('~{(.*?)}~', null, $clean2);
            $cleanResult = preg_replace('~{(.*?)}~', null, $clean3);

            preg_match_all('~<a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" (.*?)</a>~', $cleanResult, $articles);

            //return $lists; // bos geliyor. 

            if ($articles[1]) {
                foreach ($articles[1] as $article) {
                    preg_match('~<span class="h3 u-block" .*?>(.*?)</p>~', $article, $priceObject);
                    $priceWithCurrency = str_replace(',-', null, $priceObject[1]);
                    $priceWithoutCurrency = explode(' ', $priceWithCurrency)[1];
                    $price = intval(str_replace('.', null, $priceWithoutCurrency));
                    $priceList[] = $price;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $averagePrice = array_sum($priceList) / count($priceList);

        
        return new ServiceResponse(
            true,
            'Average price calculated successfully.',
            200,
            intval($averagePrice)
        );
    }

}
```

> I don't insist that these methods are just the ones that come to my mind, I want to proceed in this way, I just want to provide fast and practical transactions whenever possible. I'm sorry if I said something illogical and wrong. But I desperately need the ideas and guidance you will convey to me. Thank you from now. I'm also adding my api codes in case you want to take a look.
> The controller class is below.

````
```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\M;

use App\Core\Controller;
use App\Core\HttpResponse;
use App\Http\Requests\Api\M\PricePredictionController\CheckRequest;
use App\Interfaces\IPricePredictionService_M;

class PricePredictionController extends Controller
{
use HttpResponse;

/**
 * @var $mService
 */
private $mService;

public function __construct(IPricePredictionService_M $mService)
{
    $this->mService = $mService;
}

    /**
    * @param CheckRequest $request
    */
    public function check(CheckRequest $request)
    {
    $response = $this->mService->getByParameters(
        $request->brand_and_model,
        $request->kilometerFrom_kilometerTo,
        $request->yearFrom_yearTo,
        $request->fuelTypes ?? [],
        $request->gearBoxes ?? [],
        $request->powerFrom_powerTo,
        $request->country,
        $request->bodyType,
        $request->doors

        );

        return $this->httpResponse(
        $response->getMessage(),
        $response->getStatusCode(),
        $response->getData(),
        $response->isSuccess()
    );
}
````

}

````
> The interfaces class is below.

    ```
<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

use App\Core\ServiceResponse;

interface IPricePredictionService_M
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $brand_and_model
     * @param $kilometerFrom_kilometerTo
     * @param mixed $yearFrom_yearTo
     * @param mixed $fuelTypes
     * @param mixed $gearBoxes
     * @param mixed $powerFrom_powerTo
     * @param mixed $country
     * @param mixed $bodyType
     * @param mixed $doors
     *
     * @return ServiceResponse
     */
    public function getByParameters(
        $brand_and_model,
        $kilometerFrom_kilometerTo,
        $yearFrom_yearTo,
        $fuelTypes,
        $gearBoxes,
        $powerFrom_powerTo,
        $country,
        $bodyType,
        $doors


    ): ServiceResponse;
}
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All added. I hope I can get useful answers.